# wildfly ignores META-INF/services/java.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I am deploying an ear with the below structure to WildFly 9.0.2.

```
app.ear
   |- app-ejb.jar
   |- preferences-lib.jar
   |- META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml
```

The preferences-lib.jar contains a custom PreferencesFactory implementing java.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory. Also defined is META-INF/services/java.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory.

```
preferences-lib.jar
        |- com/**
        |- META-INF/services/java.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory
```

By default WildFly ignores META-INF folder but allows it to be imported using the jboss-deployment-structure.xml. I have tried various combinations but WildFly keeps ignoring the META-INF folder and consequently I can't use the custom preferences factory in my application.

Please help me fix this META-INF/services import issue.

Code: https://github.com/KiranMohan/wildfly-playground/tree/master/app-only-preference-factory

**Update:**
Turns out the problem is with the Java Preferences class which uses system class loader to load the service provider.
I fixed this by writing my own implementation of the Preferences.systemRoot() function where it first checks for a service provider without using the system class loader.
The code is available in the github link mentioned above.